# Why is ReadableStream locked to one reader at a time?

Tags: javascript

**Why** does `ReadableStream` lock to one reader at a time?

https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/#lock

Is this, in some way, an effect of javascript's single threaded nature?

Comment: Simply put: Because multiple readers or writers on the same stream at the same time results in a mess. Reader A gets a part of it's message and Reader B gets the other part and some part of the next message (or whatever you're sending). Writers can get into the same issue, depending on the underlying stream type.